# How can I parse a basic Discrete Mathematical statement in Java?

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, parsing, discrete-mathematics

I want to make a Java program to help people with basic discrete mathematics (that is to say, checking the truth values of statements). To do this, I need to be able to detect how many variables the user inputs, what operators there are, and what quantifiers there are, if any (∃ and ∀). **Is there a good algorithm for being able to do all these things?**

Just so you know, I don't just want a result; I want full control over their input, so I can show them the logical proof. (so doing something like passing it to JavaScript won't work).

Comment: What you are looking for is not an algorithm, but a grammar. After that, you use the grammar to generate the parser with jyacc or something like that. I would google for the grammar or ask in mathematics.stackexchange.com

Comment: You are basically looking for the features of a simplified computer algebra system. The solution will depend on your grammar, as said by @SJuan76.

Comment: And don't forget Gödels theorem! :-P

Comment: Check out [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=P+%26%26+%28Q+%7C%7C+R%29&lk=3) - it literally took them millions of lines of code to achieve what you want...

Comment: I want the grammar to be intuitive, something "your grandmother" could use.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz Millions of lines might be a bit much for just this; WA is more than just a calculator. What I'm aiming to do should end up being twice the size of the windows V/7/8 calculator at most, as that does half of the stuff I need to do.

Comment: My grandmother is unlikely to be entering first-order logic equations into a Java program...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so, your question is a bit vague, but I think I understand what you'd like to do: an educational aid that processes first-order logic formulas, showing the user step by step how to work with such formulas, right? I think the idea has merit, and it's perfectly doable, even as a one-man project, but it's not terribly easily, and you'll have to learn a lot of new things -- but they're all very interesting things, so even if nothing at all comes out of it, you'd certainly get yourself some valuable knowledge.

I'd suggest you to start small. I'd start by building a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) to *recognize* zero-order logic formulas (a machine that would decide if a formula is valid, i.e. it'd accept "A ^ B" but it'd reject "^ A ^"). Next up you'd have to devise [a way to store the formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), and then you'd be able to actually work on it. Then again, start small: a little machine that accepts valid zero-order logic formulas like `TRUE AND NOT (TRUE AND FALSE)`, and successfully reduces it step by step to true is already something that people can learn from, and it's not too hard to write. If you're feeling adventurous, add variables and make equations: `A AND TRUE = TRUE` -- it's easy to work these out with reductions and truth tables.

Things get tricky with quantifiers that bind variables, that's where the [Automated theorem proving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_theorem_proving) may come into play; but then, it all depends on exactly what you'd like to do: implementing transformations into the various normal forms, and showing the process step by step to the student would be fairly easy, and rather useful.

At any rate, I think it's a decent personal project, and you could learn a lot from it. If you're in a university, you could even get some credit for it eventually.

Answer (score 1):

The technique I have used is to parse the input string using a context free grammar.  There are many frameworks to help you do this, I have personally used [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) in the past to parse an input string into a descrete logic tree.  ANTLR allows you to define a CFG which you can map to Java types.  This allows you to map to a data structure to store and evaluate the truth value of the expression.  Of course, you would also be able to pull out the variables contained in the data structure.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid external dependencies such as libraries, as that can lead to shenanigans when I try to copyright this.

Comment: If ANTLR doesn't work with your license I would suggest at least looking into context free grammars... and maybe writing your own parser or finding one that will work with your copyright.

Comment: @Supuhstar, http://www.antlr.org/license.html it's BSD, meaning you can do anything you want with it, sell it, whatever, as long as you include a note somewhere in your docs or the like. But I'd just use a regex if the language is not too complex.

Comment: A [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) should be well enough for first-order logic, and it's a very good learning experience to write one by hand, if you have no prior experience with formal languages or syntactic and semantic analysis.

Comment: @SáT That's awesome! You should make this an answer!

Comment: @Supuhstar: There might be more to "determining the truth status" of first-order logic equations than mere parsing.  You might actually need a theorem prover, too.   They're much harder.

Comment: @IraBaxter I was just going to show them a watered-down log of the processes that the program goes through while interpreting the truth value.

Comment: A watered down theorem prover is hard.